# Multiple autogenerated stacks in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

We are using AWS amplify for React-GraphQL app with production and staging environments.

After failing to push new GraphQL fields, we found we have multiple stacks (some nested), some titled `An auto-generated nested stack` and some with **update_rollback_failed** (`stage already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation`) status.
We need to understand what created these stacks (I guess Amplify CLI code generation or push), how to identify the stack we need and if we can delete the others.